# Filter items from list while iterating, without a list comprehension

Tags: python-3.x

Say I have a list of items, and I'd like to iterate over them, performing actions on them and removing them if some criterion is not met.

I can do this really easily via a list comprehension:

```py
selection = [...]
selection = [node for node in selection
             if True in [prop['value'] for prop in node.properties
                         if prop['name'] == 'some_name']]
```

But in my case that's a fairly lengthy comprehension, and I need to stick some state-checking statements and assertions in there. I can't do that with a list comprehension. It's a shame, because using list comprehensions feels so good.

What's the best way to iterate through and filter this list?

Comment: I am sorry, but I do not understand why you cannot use comporehension list ? Also, can you feel with dummy data your selection list ?

Comment: Say during the loop I needed to do something like `if debugging: debug.print("node {} has been removed".format(node.name))` or `assert len(node.properties) > 0` - it just doesn't make sense to do that during a list comprehension.

Comment: I'm not sure dummy data is needed here - the solution is far from specific to my issue.